# How to Stream to a Global Kafka Table

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that needs to join an incoming stream against a global table, then after some processing, write out the result of an aggregate back to that table:

```
KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier supplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(
    storeName
);

Materialized<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> m = Materialized.as(
    supplier
);

GlobalKTable<String, String> table = builder.globalTable(
    topic, m.withKeySerde(
        Serdes.String()
    ).withValueSerde(
        Serdes.String()
    )
);

stream.leftJoin(
    table
    ...
).groupByKey().aggregate(
    ... 
).toStream().through(
    topic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
);
```

However, when I try to stream into the KTable changelog, I get the following error: `Invalid topology: Topic 'topic' has already been registered by another source.`

If I try to aggregate to the store itself, I get the following error: `InvalidStateStoreException: Store 'store' is currently closed`.

How can both join against the table and write back to its changelog?

If this isn't possible, a solution that involves filtering incoming logs against the store would also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `through()` is a shortcut for

```java
stream.to("topic");
KStream stream2 = builder.stream("topic");
```

Because you use `builder.stream("topic")` already, you get `Invalid topology: Topic 'topic' has already been registered by another source.` because each topic can only be consumed once. If you want to feed the data of a stream/topic into different part, you need to reuse the original `KStream` you created for this topic:

KStream stream = builder.stream("topic");

```
// this won't work
KStream stream2 = stream.through("topic");

// rewrite to
stream.to("topic");
KStream stream2 = stream; // or just omit `stream2` and reuse `stream`
```

Not sure what you mean by

> If I try to aggregate to the store itself

Comment: We are having the same issue: need to write to a topic, and then build a GKT from the same topic to use elsewhere in the topology. However, at no point we actually access the topic as a KS, it's simply referred to by name twice in to() and in StreamsBuilder.globalTable(). The result is the same though: invalid topology exception. Would you be able to clarify how to work around the limitation in this particular case?

Comment: Not 100% sure without the topology code. You can inspect the topology via `Topology#describe()` to see why (if) the topic shows up more than once as a source. Or start a new question...